# How to properly destruct a QVector of struct that contains pointer classes?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, destructor

I have a `QVector` of a struct, the struct contains many properties, some are int and some are pointer to a class. And each `TheCore` will be tie to a tab in `QTabWidget`.

```
struct TheCore {
    int score;
    ClassA *classA;
    ClassB *classB;
}

QVector<TheCore> m_coresVector;
```

In my source file, I have a function that create new TheCore and added to the coresVector. Also one of the class will be assigned to the QTabWidget on creation.

```
// create tab function
TheCore core;
core.score = 50;
core.classA = new ClassA();
core.classB = new ClassB();
ui->tabWidget->addTab(core.classA, "tab_1");
m_coresVector.append(core);
```

Then a tab close will trigger the destruct function

```
currentTabIndex = ui->tabWidget->currentIndex();
ui->tabWidget->removeTab(currentTabIndex)
delete m_coresVector[currentTabIndex].classA;
delete m_coresVector[currentTabIndex].classB;

m_coresVector.remove(currentTabIndex);
```

But I'm getting memory leak. I started a lot of tab and then closed them and the memory usage was piling up without dropping. How do I properly delete these pointer class?

Comment: You are deleting the two objects, but don't appear to be removing the element from `m_coresVector`. This would in turn result in indexes not lining up - next time the tab is closed, `currentTabIndex` may not correspond to the right `TheCore` element.

Comment: Oh I did remove the element from the vector, I'll update my post

Comment: Then the leak is likely in the code not shown. Perhaps `ClassA` and `ClassB` allocate resources and then don't properly deallocate them in their destructors. Show a [mcve]

Comment: Please read about the [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: Thanks guy, my question here is just to make sure that I didn't mess up on this part of the code leaking it. The leak is definitely from either ClassA or ClassB.

Answer (score 0):

You have options.

1. You can try using `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` for your pointers
2. Add destructor, copy-constructor and copy assignment operator to your struct (see [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), thanks G.M.)

Also I would recommend you to make it more encapsulated, hide these pointers in private section to prevent changing them from an unexpected sides and provide some interface, but probably it depends.

Also you can try to refactor your code, so your `ClassA` and `ClassB` will take in constructor `QObject* parent` as Qt classes often do. So, they will be destructed when parent destructed.

---

Actually, your "remove-tab" handling code looks ok and seems there is no any memory leak or your code sample is incomplete. You can add counter to constructors and destructor of `classA`, `classB` to ensure how many times it is created and deleted. Probably, leak is in some another place.